# Athena query using athena-express not working with req.body input

Tags: sql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I was wondering how I can query specific data from AWS Athena using `req.body` parameters. Whenever I try to run my query using `req.body` query in postman I get this error

```
Error: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:1: Incorrect number of parameters: expected 1 but found 0
    at AthenaExpress.query (C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\github_ecm_forms\ecm_input_forms\node_modules\athena-express\lib\athenaExpress.js:141:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

This is how I'm setting up postman
[image]

This is my config with the query at the bottom. It works fine if I dont include the where clause. I'm not sure of the syntax in querying Athena to use where clauses in node JS.

```js
require('dotenv').config()

const AthenaExpress = require("athena-express"),
    aws = require("aws-sdk"),
    awsCredentials = {
        region: process.env.REGION,
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESSKEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY
    };

aws.config.update(awsCredentials);

//AthenaExpress config object
const athenaExpressConfig = {
    aws, /* required */
    s3: process.env.S3BUCKET, /* optional */
    db: process.env.ATHENADB, /* optional */
    formatJson: true, /* optional default=true */
    retry: 200, /* optional default=200 */
    getStats: false /* optional default=false */
}


//Initializing AthenaExpress
const athenaExpress = new AthenaExpress(athenaExpressConfig);

module.exports = {

    getData: async (req, res) => {
        const { building_abbreviation } = req.body
      
        try {
            let results = await athenaExpress.query("SELECT * FROM building_meter_metadata WHERE building_abbreviation = ?",
                [
                    building_abbreviation
                ]
            )
            return res.json(results)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice on how to get this query to work is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using `AthenaExpress` library as today (August 10th, 2021).  The support for parameterized queries was just added to AWS Athena last month but a new version of AthenaExpress hasn't been released with support for this feature yet.

Right now, your best bet for leveraging parameterized queries would be to use the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Athena.html) directly.

Comment: I don't see [any issue created in the GitHub for AthenaExpress](https://github.com/ghdna/athena-express/issues) to request this support, you may want to create that github issue,